# Can't import audio plugin in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, import, google-cardboard

I'm creating game for google cardboard and I imported new sdk with new audio options. The problem is that after importing this error accurres:
`Effect CardboardAudio Renderer could not be found. Check that the project contains the correct native audio plugin libraries and that the importer settings are set up correctly.`

The thing that confuses me is that the library seems to be there...

What's even more confusing is that it happens only when I upgrade previous(0.6) version of sdk to the new one, if I create new project and import only new sdk everything works. Because of that I exported working plugins(from project where everything worked) folder and swapped it with existing one(in project with importing problems). After this there were same bugs so I thing the problem is in some settings inside the project, not with the plugin itself.

Do you know what can I do to fix it?